# Application starting issue websphere application server 8.5 after deployment Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, websphere-8, jenkins-cli

I am using Jenkins websphere deployer plugin to deploy application to IBM WAS 8.5.5. 
The ear deployment is successful but the start up is not successful though Jenkins shows success message.

I assume the ear (around 90MB) takes time for expansion in the remote server, and Jenkins success message is before the complete expansion. Is there a way to delay the process of startup after deployment is done.

Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot work around this issue since it requires a modification to the websphere deployer plugin. There is a known synchronization issue for large EAR files. I believe there was a pull request that fixes this issue and was merged into the codebase for v1.3 of the plugin. This version is not yet released but can be viewed on github if you wish to compile and try it out for yourself.

You will need to use maven and to manual imports into your .m2 repository to compile and test this code in jenkins.

Reference: https://github.com/jenkinsci/websphere-deployer-plugin

Comment: Thanks greg !!!!! Could you please let me know when can i expect 1.3 version. For time being any beta version will do.